# Function parameters

Tags: c, function-pointers

What I have to put as second parameter in this function? I need to understand the meaning of `int (*fn)(const char *, const struct stat *ptr, int flag).`

```
int 
ftw(const char *path, int (*fn)(const char *, const struct stat *ptr, int flag), 
int depth);
```

Thank you!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 int (*fn)(const char *, const struct stat *ptr, int flag)
```

is a pointer to a function that returns an `int` and takes a `const char*`, a `const struct stat *`, and an `int`.

If you had this function:

```
 int func (const char *s, const struct stat *ptr, int flag)
 {
      return 0;
 }
```

You could pass `func` as that argument.

Comment: I would say it is not a function, rather, a function pointer.